# "Guys did anyone of you have found my pencil box today in our class?"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs, interrogatives, do-support

> "Guys did anyone of you have found my pencil box today in our class?"

Is that example grammatical?

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not grammatically correct. Here are some ways you could modify it to make it so:

- "Guys, did any one of you find my pencil box today in our class?" (note the space between 'any' and 'one' in this version)
- "Guys, did anyone find my pencil box today in our class?"
- "Guys, has anyone found my pencil box from our class today?"
- "Guys, have any one of you found my pencil box today in our class?"

Comment: Does it seem to you that "find" is a little awkward though? If I understand the context, I might say "Guys, did anyone see my pencil case in class today? I've lost it." or "Guys, did any of you pick up my pencil case in class today? I can't find it."

Comment: @ColleenV No, not really. I think I would probably phrase it in conversation more like you did but I don't think it's awkward this way.

Comment: I think you're right - there's something off  though and I can't put my finger on it. Maybe it's how specific "in class today" is when looking for something that's lost. "Guys, has anyone seen my pencil case? " seems more natural.

Comment: I think @ColleenV is right. Usually you would use "see". To me, "Did anyone find it today?" feels like something you would say **after class** if you asked your friends **before class** if they would look for the pencil box **during class**, or if everyone had been looking for it for a couple days. **Finding** something is usually an intentional act. You have to know in advance that you are looking for it. If your friends weren't actively looking for it, they may have happened to see it, but they wouldn't really say they had found it. (Obviously, this isn't a hard rule, just a nuance).

Comment: What makes it odd to me is having the "one" after "any."  What is it doing?  I am not sure how it helps the meaning, or what connotations it lends here.  "Guys, did any of you find my pencil box..." sounds much better to me.  "Any one" is better used for something like:  "Guys, if any one of you shows up late, then NONE of us will be allowed in the stadium."

Comment: @Keiki "Finding something is usually an intentional act. " Not according to Merriam-Webster:  "transitive verb: to come upon, often accidentally". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/find If there is a problem with "find" here, I think it is that  you would probably *expect* to see  pencil cases in a classroom, so you wouldn't consider that you had "found" them. On the other hand, if you found a $100 bill lying on the floor, that would be memorable -- but not intentional.

Comment: And Dave, just to be clear, I'm not criticizing your answer, which I think is fine. The example sentence is just interesting to me.

Answer (score 2):

I take your question to ask whether or not "Guys did anyone of you have found my pencil box today in our class?" is relevant. To the best of my ability, the answer is *no.* I might suggest "Guys, did anyone find my pencil box in the classroom today?", if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: You might have wanted to have emphasized how "have found" is not the right form of the verb.  It uses the "present perfect", when the "present" form is the correct form, as you noted between the two examples you gave (original vs. your own) using the verb tenses, but didn't come out and say.